# SQL Rollback not going back to last commit

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problem with the following in SQL:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    department_dup
ORDER BY dept_no;
```

[image]

Then I ran this piece of code:

```
COMMIT;

UPDATE department_dup
SET
    dept_no = 'd011',
    dept_name = 'Quality Control'
    ;

ROLLBACK;
SELECT * from department_dup;
```

But the table is not going back to the last commit

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to do `START TRANSACTION` and you're in auto-commit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MySQL starts the session for each new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error

Option 1: Set autocomit off

```
SET autocommit = 0
```

OPtion 2: Use transaction boundaries.

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE department_dup
SET
    dept_no = 'd011',
    dept_name = 'Quality Control'
    ;

ROLLBACK;
```